# Why was the quasar question migrated to Physics.SE instead of Astronomy.SE?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

We had [a question about quasars](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137837/45702) that was quite a bit off topic.
It has been migrated to the Physics stack.

We also have an [Astronomy stack](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com), which is in beta. To me, that seems the stack that should be even better equipped to answer this question.

I don't want to criticise the decision, I'm just genuinely curious why it was migrated to Physics instead of to Astronomy. Is it because the former is graduated while the latter is in beta?

Comment: Considering it's gotten 13 upvotes there in 11 hours, I think physics is just fine.

Comment: My own (probably limited, definitely not specialist/expert) reading on the topic would suggest physics.  For ex, Stephen Hawking is probably the black hole guru most people know of best, and he's a physicist, not an astronomer.  Quasars & black holes may be astronomical objects, but this question was about explanation of their behaviour, which belongs to physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I flipped a coin, and it came up Physics.

Comment: This seems quite arbitrary

Comment: @Richard Well, I'm not super familiar with either site. No one's posted a reason to prefer one over the other either, so arbitrariness rules the day.

Comment: Wouldn't the coin come up either Statistics.SE or Money.SE?

Comment: @Keen for future reference, speaking as a Physics mod, pretty much anything that is on topic on [astronomy.SE] is also on topic on [physics.SE] (with perhaps isolated exceptions).

Answer (score 12):

Keen's choice may have been arbitrary, but in general, [migrating to beta sites isn't encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169984/194206):

> **Anna Lear:** Migrating to beta sites isn't something we encourage because beta should be all about a site figuring out its own voice rather than getting questions from elsewhere, but an occasional migration doesn't hurt much.

Comment: Given a choice between two equally valid migration destinations, where one is a graduated site, and the other a beta site, I'd be inclined to pick the graduated site over the beta unless there's a *really* compelling reason not to.

Answer (score 5):

The question should be, why not? It's perfectly on-topic on either site, and it's doing quite well where it is.